# Override OWIN OAuth Bearer Authentication with custom authentication for a specific Web API controller

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

This is an extremely niche case I think, but I'm hoping someone has come across a similar situation.

I have an ASP.NET Web API (v2) configured to use OAuth bearer tokens using the OWIN middleware, e.g.:

```
var oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(60),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>())
        };

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

I'm implementing some methods for a particular client who have their own authentication mechanism. So I created a custom authentication attribute, which I've applied to the controller I'm using for their methods.

The problem is that I'm still seeing the `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer` so I know that the middleware is still running, despite me using the `[OverrideAuthentication]` and `[OverrideAuthorization]` attributes. I've tried implementing the custom authentication as an authorization attribute too, but I think the problem is that the AuthenticationHandlers in the OWIN middleware take precedence over everything else, so the presence of an AuthorizeAttribute causes them to be applied.

How can I disable this authentication middleware for this specific controller? I wondered if the answer was to write my own authentication middleware but I'm not sure how I would prevent the Bearer Authentication from being applied too.